# En c++ con la libreria cvblob puedo hacer que etiquete los objetos que detecta

Tags: c++, opencv

Tengo este programa en c++

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    // Read image
    Mat im = imread( "blob.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );

    // Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
    SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;

    // Change thresholds
    params.minThreshold = 10;
    params.maxThreshold = 200;

    // Filter by Area.
    params.filterByArea = true;
    params.minArea = 1500;

    // Filter by Circularity
    params.filterByCircularity = true;
    params.minCircularity = 0.1;

    // Filter by Convexity
    params.filterByConvexity = true;
    params.minConvexity = 0.87;

    // Filter by Inertia
    params.filterByInertia = true;
    params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01;


    // Storage for blobs
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;


#if CV_MAJOR_VERSION < 3   // If you are using OpenCV 2

    // Set up detector with params
    SimpleBlobDetector detector(params);

    // Detect blobs
    detector.detect( im, keypoints);
#else 

    // Set up detector with params
    Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);   

    // Detect blobs
    detector->detect( im, keypoints);
#endif 

    // Draw detected blobs as red circles.
    // DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS flag ensures
    // the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob

    Mat im_with_keypoints;
    drawKeypoints( im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0,0,255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS );

    // Show blobs
    imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints );
    waitKey(0);

}
```

y como resultado me da esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito saber es que si puedo contar mediante codigo del programa cuantos objetos me detecto, cabe mencionar que siempre usare imagenes binarias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin haber usado `opencv` nunca, mirando un poco la documentación, diría que

```
SimpleBlobDetector::detect( )
```

rellena un `std::vector< cv::KeyPoint >` con los elementos encontrados.

Por lo tanto, para saber cuantos hay, bastaría con hacer

```
keypoints.size( );
```